# sum items of Flatlist on react native

Tags: sqlite, react-native

I'm making an app that makes a bill of items and the user can identify the quantity of every item
and at least there is a text tag which it shows the total price after hitting " get bill " button
it works fine , but the issue is after hitting the button the items are repeated again
[here a screenshot of the app after hitting a 'get bill' button]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/slOWN.jpg

this is the code :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, FlatList, Dimensions, Text } from "react-native";
import * as SQLite from "expo-sqlite";
import { Button } from "react-native-elements";
import NumericInput from "react-native-numeric-input";
const db = SQLite.openDatabase("db.db");
class CreateBill extends Component {
constructor() {
super();
this.state = {
  items: [],
  itemsList: [],
  products: [],
  totalPrice: 0,
};
}
async componentDidMount() {
console.log("did mount");
db.transaction((tx) => {
  tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM products2", [], (tx, results) => {
    var temp = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < results.rows.length; ++i) {
      temp.push(results.rows.item(i));
    }
    this.setState({
      products: temp,
    });
  });
  });
 }
 checkItems = () => {
 this.state.items.forEach((item) => {
  this.state.products.forEach((product) => {
    if (item === product.code) {
      console.log("equals", item, product.code);
      this.state.itemsList.push({ product, number: 0 });
    } else {
      console.log("doesnt equal", item.item, product.code);
    }
  });
  });
 };

 getPrice = () => {
  let price = 0;
  this.state.itemsList.forEach((element) => {
  price = element.number * element.product.price;
  });
  this.setState({ totalPrice: price });
  };
  render() {
  this.state.items = this.props.route.params.items;
  this.checkItems();
  return (
  <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <FlatList
      data={this.state.itemsList}
      extraData={this.state}
      style={{ marginTop: 50, flex: 1, width: Dimensions.width }}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.product.id}
      renderSeparator={() => (
        <View
          style={{
            backgroundColor: "#1B73B4",
            height: 0.6,
          }}
        />
      )}
      renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
        console.log("item", item);
        return (
          <View
            style={{
              flexDirection: "row",
              width: Dimensions.width,
              paddingStart: 20,
              alignItems: "center",
            }}
            key={item}
          >
            <View style={{ flex: 0.5, alignItems: "center" }}>
              <Text style={{ fontSize: 24 }}>{item.product.name}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={{ flex: 0.5, justifyContent: "center" }}>
              <NumericInput
                value={this.state.itemsList[index].number}
                onChange={(value) => {
                  let item1 = this.state.itemsList[index];
                  item1.number = value;
                  console.log(
                    this.state.itemsList[index].product.name,
                    this.state.itemsList[index].number
                  );
                }}
                totalWidth={140}
                totalHeight={45}
                iconSize={25}
                maxValue={this.state.itemsList[index].product.units}
                minValue={0}
                valueType="integer"
                rounded
                textColor="#1B73B4"
                iconStyle={{ color: "white" }}
                rightButtonBackgroundColor="#1B73B4"
                leftButtonBackgroundColor="#1B73B4"
              />
            </View>
          </View>
        );
      }}
    />
    <Text>{this.state.totalPrice}</Text>
    <Button title="get bill" onPress={() => this.getPrice()} />
   </View>
  );
 }
 }
  export { CreateBill };
```

Comment: I solved this situation by getting the data from sqlite on the screen before this screen  and it works fine , but i still need an answer for this question , why FlatList repeats the items on this code

Answer (score 0):

In your case `reduce` is the best option:

[Documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Example:

```
const totalPrice = this.state.itemsList.reduce((total, element) => 
    total += element.number * element.product.price
,0);
this.setState({ totalPrice });
```

Comment: i think the issue is with setState() but i don't know a replacement for it